# Transistor in the NOT Gate

Tags: transistors

How can the "input" be supplied with x volts, and the "output" be supplied with y volts? To my understanding, the input and output are connected to a power source, such as a battery - how can you have 0 volts on the wire going out and 2.9 on the wire coming in?

If we are manipulating the voltage to manipulate whether the transistor functions as an open switch or a closed switch, why have a transistor? We are the ones connecting and disconnecting the 3 V battery to manipulate the transistor's function as a switch - Why can't we just use a regular switch?

If you can provide any insight into the questions I have, I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case a BJT transistor you have 2 circuits overlapping with each other so you have to measure current and voltage drops seperately and then add them.

Answer (score 1):

*How can the "input" be supplied with x volts, and the "output" be supplied with y volts?*

This is actually one of the useful functions of a transistor - it can be configure to use a small signal from a tiny switch or from the output of a micro-controller to switch a much larger load that the original switch could not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8QNpC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A transistor used as a simple power amplifier.*

*... how can you have 0 volts on the wire going out and 2.9 on the wire coming in?*

It depends on the configuration. In Figure 1 when the switch is closed (pulling the input high) the transistor will turn on pulling its collector low. This is effectively an inverter.

*If we are manipulating the voltage to manipulate whether the transistor functions as an open switch or a closed switch, why have a transistor?*

- Power gain. (See Figure 1 again.)
- Voltage level changing. (e.g. 3 V to 24 V.)
- Frequency of operation. The transistor can switch at far higher frequencies than a mechanical contact.
- No moving parts on the transistor and no arcing. Let the mechanical switch handle signal currents which won't cause an arc and let the transistor handle the high currents without worry about arcing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use switches. If you want to see a complete computer in operation that just uses relays (mechanical switches that can be opened and closed), then look at [Harry Porter's relay computer](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/).

So you can use regular switches. You could even operate them manually, if you wanted to "be the computer" for a while. (I did something like this, way back when, in order to learn about how computers operated. I decoded each instruction myself, by hand, and then ran the program by toggling switches on pieces of paper with a pencil.) Early calculators I used even did this using mechanical, rotating cams and lifters, etc.

However, in order to get lots of "state" that operates very fast and with relatively small size and low power, transistors are the answer. To make them work well, you need to have a "waterfall" of electrons flowing between two points of differing voltage, from a high point to a low point, so that a signal can flow from left to right across that waterfall. Without that, the signal doesn't move across from left to right.

You get to pick the differing voltage, so long as it is consistent with the transistors you are using. They have their own requirements, so you have to meet them.

You could assign many different states to slightly different voltages, so that a single "wire" could hold lots of different states. And that's been done. But it turns out that just having two states (or three, on occasion) works out very, very well in practice and provides a lot of immunity to noise.

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

The upper left corner is a region that has been set aside as one valid NOT gate result. Any voltage from \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ is converted (inverted) to voltage that is guaranteed to be from \$3\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$5\:\textrm{V}\$. The lower right corner is the opposite region -- the other valid NOT gate result, where any voltage from \$3\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ is converted (inverted) to voltage that is guaranteed to be from \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$1\:\textrm{V}\$.

In between on the chart is a no-man's land where you can see curves as they vary from one region to the other. In between, you can't be sure of the state. So you avoid those regions and move as quickly as possible from one valid region to the other. Those curves there show differences between different transistors with different numbers of "loads" attached to them (receivers "looking" at the values.) It's important that variations in device behavior and variations in circuit attachments still work well, regardless, and setting up these rules help to make sure that there is little chance for confusion.